# SWT "slim look" buttons and scrollbars

Tags: eclipse, swt, rcp, jface

Eclipse 3.5 (on the Mac, at least) now has a slimmer look to its buttons and scroll bars, whereas previous versions' buttons and scroll bars used the larger, "puffier" look.  I would like to adopt this same look in my RCP app, but I can't find in the SWT or JFace APIs anywhere how to force the widgets to use this slimmer look.  How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're now using native Cocoa versus the previous Carbon implementation.  There is no API for it.

Comment: Ah yes, this does seem to be the case.  I just looked at the Carbon version of 3.5SR2 and then the Cocoa version, and the slim look is not in the Carbon build.  Thanks!